# Media queries ignored when element has style on it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a sidebar that slides from 0px to 160px from the left when I press a button.

That is done with this javascript code, I wanted to add css queries to make my website responsive but that just broke the sliding sidebar

```
function MenuButton() {
  var x = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1281px)");
  var min = "0px";
  var max = "160px";
  if(x.matches)
  {
    min = "50px";
    max = "160px";
  }

  if (document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width == max) {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = min;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = max;
    }
}
```

This is the css query i am using

```
@media (min-width: 1281px) {

}
```

When the button is pressed it adds `style="width: 0px;"` to my code, ignoring the media query when i want to resize the window. I use a css class for my style and that class is responsive.

How can i make this work?

[Here is an example](https://codepen.io/DavidA002/pen/gQjxOb) of the issue i'm having, you can try resizing the window but once the button is clicked the responsive design is gone

Comment: I would say that `x.matches` doesn't evaluate to `true` so `min` is `0px`

Comment: @RyanWilson it works, i've tested it. The sidebar is responsive until i press the button and `style="width: 0px";` is added to the html. That's where the website breaks. When that line is added the button still works but the responsiveness is gone

Comment: I don't see how it works if it is setting the `width` to `0px`, which is the default  value of `min`.

Comment: @RyanWilson I'm sorry, my mistake. The start width of the sidebar is 160, so when the button is pressed it gets to 0 and if its pressed again its 160 again, it works perfectly.

Comment: So are you saying that you no longer have an issue?

Comment: @RyanWilson No, i'm just clarifying something that i didn't include in the question, That was my mistake, the code is good and the issue is still there

Comment: @SenaCarbtc can you give us your html/css codes?

Comment: @SenaCarbtc It sounds like the inline styling is overriding your CSS, why not just wrap your sidebar in a div and add a class to it to hide or show on the button click, and leave the responsive stuff for the actual sidebar inside your  CSS and media queries.

Comment: @RyanWilson even if i do that it still doesn't solve the issue, once the button is clicked it remembers the last width, when the window is resized I'll have to click the button again to change the width again.

Comment: @K.C. Here you go: https://codepen.io/DavidA002/pen/gQjxOb